# After casting float to float/int returned different result

Tags: c++, c, types, casting

In my original code it is,

```
approach += sign * (1.0/n);
```

But after adding a float cast to it:

```
approach += sign * (float)(1.0/n);
```

the final result changed. `approach` is defined as `float` while `sign` and `n` are `integers`.
 From what I've learned, 1.0/n should cast `n` to float and in the first version it should be equivalent of

```
approach += sign * (1.0/(float)n);
```

and `(1.0/(float)n)` is a float itself, casting a float to it shouldn't make any difference.
Obviously there is something wrong in my logic, please kindly point out.

Comment: Please show you inputs and your outputs, and expected outputs.

Comment: Both `approach += sign * (1.0/n);` and `approach += sign * (float)(1.0/n);` should give you the same result.

Comment: `1.0/n should cast n to float` no, it will cast it to double

Comment: yes, `1.0f/n` will cast to float. But still only the precision will change

Comment: All three give the same value. Are you sure that with `approach += ...` you aren't adding to your previous result? AKA "finger trouble".

Comment: Please show the previous value of `approach`, the values of `sign` and `n`, and the results you're getting with the two versions.

Comment: You should really keep all your floating point values in doubles in C.  I can't remember when I last used single precision other than for testing purposes.

Comment: @TomKarzes `float` can be useful if you're creating large arrays and you want to keep memory use to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.0/n` should cast `n` not to `float` but to `double` because `1.0` is `double`.

`(1.0/(float)n)` is not a `float` but `double` because `1.0` is `double` and `(float)n` will be promoted to `double` before computation.

You can use `1.0f/n` with `float` literal `1.0f` (with `f` as suffix) to have `n` be casted to `float` and do the calculation.

With this code, if the size of `float` and `double` in the environment differs, you can see size of `(float)(1.0/n)` and `(1.0/(float)n)` differs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float approach, init = 3.14;
    int sign = 1, n = 10;

    printf("sizeof(float) = %zu\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("sizeof(double) = %zu\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(long double) = %zu\n", sizeof(long double));
    printf("sizeof((1.0/n)) = %zu\n", sizeof((1.0/n)));
    printf("sizeof((1.0f/n)) = %zu\n", sizeof((1.0f/n)));
    printf("sizeof((float)(1.0/n)) = %zu\n", sizeof((float)(1.0/n)));
    printf("sizeof((1.0/(float)n)) = %zu\n", sizeof((1.0/(float)n)));

    approach = init;
    approach += sign * (1.0/n);
    printf("(1.0/n) : %.30f\n", approach);
    approach = init;
    approach += sign * (1.0f/n);
    printf("(1.0f/n) : %.30f\n", approach);
    approach = init;
    approach += sign * (float)(1.0/n);
    printf("(float)(1.0/n) : %.30f\n", approach);
    approach = init;
    approach += sign * (1.0/(float)n);
    printf("(1.0/(float)n) : %.30f\n", approach);
    return 0;
}
```